# SQL select from 3 table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 3 tables:

```
ssu:
    id (primary key)
     ssu_number

agreement:
    agreement_id
    agreement_number 
    agreement_status_fk
    agreement_type_fk

agreement_ssu:
    ssu_id 
    agreement_fk
```

I need to select ssu_number which occur at least 2 times as ssu_id in table agreement_ssu, which have agreement_status_fk = 1 and agreement_type_fk = 1.

Here is my select but i think it will be not work (i cant test it now):

```
select
    *
from
    asd.ssu p
    join tdd.agreement_ssu ap on p.id = ap.ssu
    join tdd.agreement ae on ae.id = ap.AGREEMENT_FK
    join
    (
        select
            ssu_id
        from
            tdd.agreement_ssu
        group by
            ssu_ID
        having
            count( ssu_id ) > 1 )
    y on y.ssu_id = p.ID
where
    ae.AGREEMENT_TYPE_FK = 1
    and
    ae.agreement_status_fk = 1;
```

Example

```
ssu
| id | ssu_number|
|  1 | 2000      |
|  2 | 2001      |
|  3 | 2002      |
|  4 | 2003      |

agreement
| agreement_id | agreement_number | agreement_status_fk | agreement_type_fk |
|      1       |     da5as6d      |           1         |          1        |
|      2       |     d57as6       |           1         |          2        | 
|      3       |     dsjks6d      |           2         |          2        |
|      4       |     d4s7sad      |           1         |          1        |
|      5       |     d43790d      |           1         |          1        |
|      6       |     d437s6d      |           1         |          1        |
|      7       |     d4aq36d      |           1         |          2        |

agreement_ssu
| ssu_id | agreement_fk |
|    1   |      1       |
|    1   |      2       |
|    2   |      6       |
|    2   |      4       |
|    2   |      7       |
|    3   |      3       |
|    4   |      5       |
```

And from select i should get only ssu_number: 2001 (occurs 2 times in agreement_ssu and both have agreement_status_fk = 1 and agreement_type_fk = 1)

```
| ssu_number |
|   2001     |
```

Comment: Which is it?  SQL Server or Oracle?  It can't be both.  And do we have to guess what "doesnt work" means?  Or would you care to tell us what's going wrong?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Did you receive an error message? If so, what was it. Provide sample data and expected results. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Fix your field names first ...

Answer (score 1):

I have not setup the exact scenario, and not checked this code, but I think something along these lines is what you want:

```
SELECT
    ssu.ssu_number
FROM
    ssu
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            assu.ssu_id
        FROM    
            agreement_ssu assu
        INNER JOIN
            agreement a on a.agreement_id = assu.agreement_fk
        GROUP BY
            assu.ssu_id     
        WHERE
            a.agreement_status_fk = 1
            AND a.agreement_type_fk = 1  
        HAVING
            COUNT(assu.ssu_id) > 1
    ) IT ON ssu.id = IT.ssu_id
```

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

This should do it,

```
SELECT SSU.SSU_NUMBER
FROM SSU
  JOIN AGREEMENT_SSU
    ON SSU.ID = AGREEMENT_SSU.SSU_ID
  JOIN AGREEMENT 
    ON AGREEMENT.ID = AGREEMENT_SSU.AGREEMENT_FK
WHERE AGREEMENT.AGREEMENT_STATUS_FK = 1
  AND AGREEMENT.AGREEMENT_TYPE_FK = 1
GROUP BY SSU.SSU_NUMBER
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```